# How to query MySQL with a PHP variable and have the results displayed via Google Charts?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, google-visualization

I am just getting started using the Google Charts API with PHP and MySQL and would love a little assistance.  I would like the results of a MySQL query that Google Charts uses to be based off of a variable.  Basically I have this and it works as expected.

displayChart.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                   var jsonData = $.ajax({
                        url: "test3.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false
                    }).responseText;
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

                    var options = {
                        fontName: 'Trebuchet MS',
                        colors: ['#22671F'],
                        title: 'Handicap History',
                        hAxis: {title: 'Revision Date', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
```

test3.php

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT rev_date, ndx FROM revisions WHERE player_id=7");      
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Rev', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Index', 'type' => 'number')
    );
    $rows = array();
    while ($nt = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['rev_date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['ndx']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this in test3.php

```
$result = $connect->query("SELECT rev_date, ndx FROM revisions WHERE player_id='$playerID'");      
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Rev', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Index', 'type' => 'number')
    );
    $rows = array();
    while ($nt = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['rev_date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['ndx']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;
```

How can I pass a value for the $playerID variable to the test3.php page?  Can I pass a variable when the `url: "test3.php"` piece is called in the ajax and use a $_GET on test3.php?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You are running a `sync` ajax command instead of `async`. This may result in browsers locking up - beware. You should embed some php code `<?php ... code ... ?>` and output results where the javascript code is; then you wouldn't have to worry about async/sync issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$.ajax()` method, you can use the `data` property in the `options`.

Example:

```
               var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "test3.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    data: { 'playerID' : 123 }
                }).responseText;
```

Following up on my comment to your question regarding SYNC commands... you should use the `callback` methods available to fire the next function.

Comment: So, lets say the JavaScript code is wrapped in a php function (displayHeader($playerID)).  Where you have '123' as the value for playerID to be passed to test3.php, how can I pass $playerID variable instead of 123?  Is it possible?  Thanks for your pointers too

Comment: `data: { 'playerID' : <?php echo $playerID; ?> }` -- This might throw a syntax error on some IDE's, but it'll be fine, assuming `$playerID` exists and is an `INT`

Comment: Awesome, thanks Rob.  Last question, how can I grab the playerID on the test3.php page?  Using at $_GET or $_POST in PHP doesn't seem to grab it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind, I got it, error in my real escape string syntax.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `test3.php?player=your_id` and use `$playerid = (int)$_GET['player'];` to get the param from the url